# Scraping data 5 websites and comparison product price in websites

Tags: web, comparison, scrape, price

I have 5 datasheets from scraping 5 websites. And there are more than 1000 products
So i want to compare all of product. But products name are different. How can i do this with coding you think ?

Example List

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4qqw.png)

And i want to turn into this table. 
Like this table in below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcaTP.png)
Is this possible?

Comment: Both the image links are same, moreover instead of link try to use <img> tag for inline image

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt notice i fixed now